# Why is `keyof T` giving `string | number` instead of an enum of keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I have the following type:

```
type BaseObject = {
    id: string,
    attributes: {
        readonly createdAt: Date,
        readonly updatedAt: Date,
    },
    relationships?: {
        [key: string]: RelationEntity<BaseObject> | RelationEntity<BaseObject[]>,
    },
}
```

This type is extended for specific entities like:

```
type Warehouse = BaseObject & {
    relationships?: {
        account: RelationEntity<Account>,
        products: RelationEntity<Product[]>,
    },
}
```

Now I tried the following as to constrain the possible values of the `include` property of `params` to the known relationships of the given type:

```
function listEntities<T extends BaseObject>(params?: { include?: keyof T['relationships'] })
...
```

When compiling `listEntities<Warehouse>({ include })` this should enable the compiler to check that a hardcoded value for `include` is actually an existing relationship of the given object. However, my IDE and the compiler convert `keyof T['relationships']` to `string | number`, so it doesn't work.

I have seen examples of functions like:

```
function listEntities<T extends BaseObject, Includes extends keyof T['relationships']>(...)
```

However, this means the function gets another required type argument, which I want to avoid, as all the information (as I see it) is given by the first parameter `T`.

**Plot twist:** I noticed that `T['relationships']` becomes `string | number`, but `T` is correctly inferred as `"id" | "attributes" | "relationships"`. Why does this make a difference?

My question also applies to loose types (which is how I would use it, since the `params` type contains a lot more options than just `include`):

```
type ListParameters<T extends BaseObject> = {
    include: keyof T['relationships'],  // also inferred as `string | number` by the compiler
}
```

I have created a playground demonstrating my problem: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&target=7&module=1&ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgeQEYCsIGNhQLxQDeAUFGVAJYAmAXFAsAE4UB2A5gDSnlzBMWoArsAgI6JcpKiMIcKgHsWAGxBQsM3hCoBBYHQAimrlPIaFy1YLBVNOvVEMjj5AL7OyMpbwqKEACwowBAB%20cW4TAG0AawgQOgZmdgBdOgAlCC9gHxYAURYs0AAeeCQ0TBwAPigAHyh0zOy8gpBixBQMbGAIpIr3KDdiF2JiUEg6jO9FJooigBUqgglyG2A4Olm%20pVYosSJwqSQlADN4-nY%20yU9bU8TOfYGhkfBoAHU4GT95QSR8WDayzpQABke0uEyyvgCQVCoJMUDgWCwX3yaXBjXyMxa2kRyOAvXuXEeo2gABkKAwAArvOAAWwgIkYCEKsygEAAHiIWFQEH9Sh1Kr8qYwsnAlIUlmRWFglIIqBA6DEQPIjlBZhEAORXCEsfyBBDqpIcMgAemN8KUCHklBYRwgjBkVHhPIABglWGwalAWIIaag7c6oKhVMA-NAkTSwBQlHbBhVhkdBCwcNkoFsGNMsqJmayORAuTySu1yniABRgak0kJ0MmUiv0u1M%20YASmIErUvnk0YAdEp5GwS%20q08AMxRRGpRdHHQB3GZ%20KDlxi0%20uMmjqo0L2kIJsAbkGwyHI6zbw%20XyQFRLhGt0tl8qg6oRSMTwHV-R3klN5qUUCOrAgxAPGKZkyx4QJ83wQOel5SjKcp0PeOKJi%20Lhvu%20Zr%20F8SiOmAjDyFQghYNAcAsKy9ryIwxBAA).

Comment: Can you create a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) that is clearly demonstrating the error please ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, see the post for a link to the playground.

Comment: You are going to get `string | number` because of the string index in `BaseObject['relationships']`.  To get the specific keys you would have to kill that index somehow.  Maybe make `BaseObject` generic?  I get what you are trying to do by making sure that extending classes must only add relationships of a certain type but the string index is troublesome with `keyof`.

Comment: See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures

Comment: Does this work? https://tsplay.dev/QmbYBN instead of doing `account: RelationEntity<Account>` I am moving that mapping into the `BaseObject`.

Comment: So basically, my problem is the `[key: string]: RelationEntity<BaseObject> | RelationEntity<BaseObject[]>` in the `BaseObject`. That helps a lot, thanks! Thanks for the suggestion; it works, but only in a limited fashion as there are more parts of the objects that are extended by each entity. I'll work out a solution and post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Linda Paiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431574/linda-paiste), it became clear that the inference doesn't work because of the union with `BaseObject`:

```
type Warehouse = BaseObject & {
    relationships?: {
        account: RelationEntity<Account>,
        products: RelationEntity<Product[]>,
    },
}
```

This results in the following type:

```
type Warehouse = {
    id: string,
    attributes: {
        readonly createdAt: Date,
        readonly updatedAt: Date,
    },
    relationships?: {
        [key: string]: RelationEntity<BaseObject> | RelationEntity<BaseObject[]>,
        account: RelationEntity<Account>,
        products: RelationEntity<Product[]>,
    },
}
```

So `keyof Warehouse['relationships']` would give `'account' | 'products' | string | number` which reduces to `string | number`, since `'account'` and `'products'` are both strings.

### My solution

I ended up reducing the `BaseObject` to bare minimum:

```
type BaseObject = {
    type: string,
    id: string,
}
```

and moving the constraint `[key: string]: RelationEntity<BaseObject> | RelationEntity<BaseObject[]>` into a separate type:

```
// only used for constraining type arguments
type TemplateObject = BaseObject & {
    attributes?: {
        [key: string]: any
    },
    relationships: {
        [key: string]: RelationEntity<TemplateObject> | RelationEntity<TemplateObject[]>,
    },
}
```

The specific entities still extend the `BaseObject`:

```
type Warehouse = BaseObject & {
    relationships: {
        account: RelationEntity<Account>,
        products: RelationEntity<Product[]>,
    },
}
```

Additionally, I made a utility to add the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` attributes when appropriate:

```
type Retrievable<T extends TemplateObject> = T & {
    attributes: {
        readonly createdAt: Date,
        readonly updatedAt: Date,
    },
}
```

And to be able to remove the `?` in `relationships?`, since that property is only present when retrieving an object from the API, also two utilities for making creatable and updatable types:

```
type Creatable<T extends TemplateObject> = {
    [key in Extract<keyof T, 'type' | 'attributes'>]: T[key]
}

type Updatable<T extends TemplateObject> = {
    [key in Extract<keyof T, 'type' | 'id' | 'attributes'>]: T[key]
}
```

#### Usage

Using the `TemplateObject`, I can now constrain type arguments (see the three utilities above), but in usage, when T is given to be e.g. a `Warehouse`, the possible attributes and relationships are well defined, and so now the compiler and IDE can correctly infer the possible values of `include`.

**Additionally,** I found that it is possible to not only use `keyof T['relationships']` or `keyof T['attributes']` to constrain parameters, but also:

```
type ListParameters<T extends Retrievable<TemplateObject>> = {
    ...
    sort: keyof T['attributes'] | `-${keyof T['attributes']},
}
```

For a `Warehouse`, this infers the possible values for `sort` as: `'-createdAt' | '-updatedAt' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt'`. For objects with more attributes, those are also included.
Note: only works in TypeScript >=4.1 afaik.